# Simplifying $ (1 - \frac{\sqrt{3-i}}{2})^{24} $

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I've been brushing up on complex analysis for fun recently from the book "Complex Analysis with Applications" by Richard A. Silverman and I've had trouble simplifying (problem 15(c) ch.1) $$ (1 - \frac{\sqrt{3-i}}{2})^{24} $$ to the degree I want.

The back of the book says that the answer is $ (2 - \sqrt 3 )^{12} $, but I'm struggling to figure out how.

When I first tackled the problem I figured I'd use De Moivres but hit a wall since in polar form.
$$ 3-i = \sqrt 10 ( \cos(\tan^{-1}(\frac{-1}{3}) + i \sin(\tan^{-1}(\frac{-1}{3}) ) $$
I failed to find a way to simplify  $ \tan^{-1}(\frac{-1}{3}) $ into a nicer expression. Since to move forward I'd then have to take the root of that polar form and then still take the whole quantity to the 24th power I assume I have to simplify $ \tan^{-1}(\frac{-1}{3}) $ first before I can do anything else.

I've been thinking about this for a few days so any help or suggestions on what I missed would be appreciated

Comment: I think it should be $\sqrt{3}-i$, not $\sqrt{3-i}$.

Comment: Does changing that fix it? It must be typo in the book then I guess because it certainly says $ \sqrt{3-i} $. Anyway thanks!

Comment: Haven't tried it, but note that $(\sqrt{3}-i)/2$ is a root of unity so $1-(\sqrt{3}-i)/2$ has nice polar form which should fix the problem.

Comment: yeah I just verified you were right lol. The rest of the problems with the chapter were nice and easy so I was stumped. I always never assume its typos for too long oh well!.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by user10354138 in the comments, the $ \sqrt{3-i} $ in the problem should be $ \sqrt{3} - i$.

Now, $(1-\frac{\sqrt{3} - i}{2})^2 = 1 - (\sqrt{3} - i) + (\frac{\sqrt{3}-i}{2})^2 = 1 - (\sqrt{3}-i)+1 = 2 - \sqrt{3} + i$.

Therefore $(1-\frac{\sqrt{3} - i}{2})^{24} = (2-\sqrt{3}+i)^{12}$

Comment: I believe the question wanted an answer in the form $ a+bi $.